# How to access google cloud vision API in python program?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have signed up for free trial in google cloud platform.I created a project and **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**.I got a json file also.I installed required packages using

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
pip install google-cloud
```

Now i need to access text extraction from image API from google in my python program.My code is([here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/vision-usage.html))

```
from google.cloud import vision
client = vision.Client()
with open('./image.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
 image = client.image(content=image_file.read())
texts = image.detect_text()
print texts[0].description
```

I have JSON file,client id,Client secret.How to integrate these credintials in above code to access google api?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to access the cloud vision API locally since on App Engine it should "just work".

To authenticate using a service account JSON keyfile you need to point to it using an environment variable:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/keyfile.json"
```

You can also authenticate using the Google Cloud SDK if it's available

```
$ gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/google-cloud-auth.html#overview